# Get value in dropdown, Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to edit/update the value of an item but I can't get its value from database. I have something like this in my database

```
Products table
   -id
   -category_id
   -sub_category_id
   -name
Category table
   -id
   -category
Sub Category table
   -id
   -sub_category
```

In my form, I have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxHJ6.png).  What should I do if the category_id in my products table exist, it should display its corresponding category name? I tried to use something like this in my form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label"> Category</label>
        <select name="category_id" id="category" class="custom-select select">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
               <?php
                   foreach ($category as $row) {
                       echo '<option value="' . isset($products->category_id) ? $row['id'] : ''  . '">' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
                 }
               ?>
      </select>
   </div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="" class="control-label">Sub Category</label>
      <select name="sub_category_id" id="subcategory" class="custom-select select">
<option value="<?php isset($products->sub_category_id) ? $products->sub_category_id : ''; ?>">Select Sub Category</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Here's my controller

```
 public function edit_product($id)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Update Product';

    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_header');
    $products = new Admin_model;
    $data['category'] = $this->Admin_model->category();
    $data['products'] = $products->edit_product($id);
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_topnav');
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_sidebar');
    $this->load->view('../admin/products/manage_product', $data);
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_footer');
}
```

And my model

```
public function edit_product($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where("products", array('id' => $id));
    return $query->row();
}

public function category()
{
    $response = array();

    $this->search(array(), 'date_created');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get('categories');
    $response = $query->result_array();

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each category that you're printing in the select box, check if the category id is the same as the product's category id. If they're the same, add 'selected' to the option:

```
           <?php
               foreach ($category as $row) {
                   echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
                   if ($row['id'] == $products->category_id) {
                        echo ' selected'
                   }
                   echo '>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
             }
           ?>
```

This selects the product's category name.

---

If your subcategory has a parent_id, the method to get all the subcategories for a certain category would look something like this (model):

```
public function sub_category($parent_id) {
    return $this->db->get_where('subcategories', array('parent_id' => $parent_id)->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function edit_product($id)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Update Product';

    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_header');
    $products = new Admin_model;
    $data['products'] = $products->edit_product($id);
    $data['category'] = $this->Admin_model->category();
    $data['subcategory'] = $this->Admin_model->sub_category($data['products']->category_id);
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_topnav');
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_sidebar');
    $this->load->view('../admin/products/manage_product', $data);
    $this->load->view('../admin/template/admin_footer');
}
```

And select the product's subcategory in the view:

```
       <?php
           foreach ($subcategory as $row) {
               echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
               if ($row['id'] == $products->sub_category_id) {
                    echo ' selected'
               }
               echo '>' . $row['sub_category'] . '</option>';
         }
       ?>
```

You would probably also need to add some Javascript to your view to load the corresponding subcategories when the value of the category select is changed, but that's going too far off topic for this question to explain here.

---

When using the same form for insert and update, check if `$products` exists first:

```
       <?php
           foreach ($category as $row) {
               echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '"';
               if (isset($products) && $row['id'] == $products->category_id) {
                    echo ' selected'
               }
               echo '>' . $row['category'] . '</option>';
         }
       ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marleen, but how should I get the value of the subcategory?

Comment: I tried to add this in my Controller 

`$data['subcategory'] = $this->Admin_model->sub_category();`

And tried this in the form 

`<label for="<?php if($subcategory->parent_id == $category->id && $products->sub_category_id == $subcategory->id){ echo 'selected'; } $subcategory['sub_category']; ?>" class="control-label">Sub Category</label>`

Where the `parent_id = category->id` but still won't work

Comment: Sorry for asking late but I'm having error in my form when I'm going to use it for inserting new data. On the category dropdown, it says `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message:  Undefined variable: products Filename: products/manage_product.php Line Number: 33` so I tried to add something like this on controller `$data['products'] = $this->Admin_model->products();` but it gave me an error `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: When using the same form for insert and update, you need to check if `$products` exists before doing the comparision in the loop, see my updated answer above.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, @Marleen, thanks. How should I get the sub_category populated? I something like [this](https://codeshare.io/eVxLwl) in the view

Comment: Thought the code should work because the subcategory dropdown is dependent to category dropdown, but when I select a category, the subcategory dropdown isn't populated.

Comment: I also tried to add `$data['subcategory'] = $this->Admin_model->get_subcategory();` in the Controller which calls the function in the [Model](https://codeshare.io/Pd3lJX). But still, the subcategory dropdown isn't populated

Comment: PHP can't react to user actions without re-loading the page. If you want to update the subcategories select when you change the category select, you need to use JavaScript. That's going too far off topic to explain here, search for "dependant dropdown" and "ajax".